# forEach error in Ionic android app after deploy

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have created and Android app with Angular/Ionic5/Capacitor.

When I deploy and install the app in emulator or even in many real devices, it works as expected. But in some devices, it just stucked in white screen. After debugging one of this devices I found out this error:

[image]

And here is tscpnfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,  
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "shared/*": [
        "app/shared/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

EDIT----------

I changed compiler target to es5, but know I get another error:

[image]

Comment: did u solve it? i am facing the same issue

Comment: @AndreasHadjithoma Sorry I can't even remember. I had a lot of problems with Ionic which never found a solution for them. I just started to learn React Native for some months and created my project from scratch.